# Show images in a plot using matplotlib with a coloured frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, machine-learning

I want to plot a graph with images on it. I am doing k-means clustering and after that, I want to show each image on its cluster with the same frame colour.

I have some code which basically places images on the graph with a black frame

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.clf()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

# add a first image
for i in range(0, len(dataset['val'].path)):    
    ab = AnnotationBbox(OffsetImage(img, zoom=.15, cmap='gray'),
                        [reduced_data[i][0], reduced_data[i][1]],
                        frameon=True,
                        xybox=(10, 10),
                        xycoords='data',
                        boxcoords="offset points",
                        arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"))

    ax.add_artist(ab)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

I was checking some tutorials on the `scickit learn` documentation and also I checked the `AnnotationBbox` and `OffsetImage` constructors in `matplotlib` webpage with no results. I was wondering if there is a way to change the frame colour of the images inserted in the plot so it matches the color I am giving to each cluster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the bounding box of your AnnotationBbox using `bboxprops=dict(edgecolor='red')`. 
A minimal example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = OffsetImage(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))
ab1 = AnnotationBbox(im, (0.5, 0.5),
                    bboxprops =dict(edgecolor='red'))
ab2 = AnnotationBbox(im, (0.75, 0.75),
                    bboxprops =dict(edgecolor=[0.2,1.,0.5]  ))

ax.add_artist(ab1)
ax.add_artist(ab2)
plt.show()
```

which gives,

[image]