# How to do circle clipping for matplotlib AnnotationBbox?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to insert images within axes, and I found answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475489/5855131) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344265/5855131), they use `OffsetImage` and `AnnotationBbox`, which is very nice.

My issue is I would like to add circle clipping to images or AnnotationBbox as similar effect as [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_clip_path.html). I tried do some processing to my image data, but got non-smooth edges. Is there any clipping related `AnnotationBbox` that I am unaware of to get smooth circular clipping with **smooth** edges, such as `set_clip_path` and `set_clip_box`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox
from skimage.morphology import disk


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.2, 7.2/2))

# image data
img = np.arange(100*100, dtype=np.float).reshape((100, 100))
mask = disk(49.5).astype(bool)
img[~mask] = None

im = OffsetImage(img)
# frame is on for better visualization
ab1 = AnnotationBbox(im, (0.5, 0.5), frameon=True)

ax.add_artist(ab1)
```

[image]

Comment: To get an antialiased border, you might try to draw a thin white (or even black) circle on top of the image.  Or, you could try to upscale the image to a much higher resolution and only then apply the masking.

Comment: This might be a solution by overlay a circle with proper linewidth:)